# Java/Discord.js ReferenceError: X is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im very new at this and I have created a working levelsystem that stores the data in a JSON for a specific discord, after they reached certain amount on "experience", they get promoted and get access to more and more backend channel. Sort of a rewardsystem where users have access to easier communication with me and my team(Im a contentcreator).

I know that this code is far from perfect but with my current knowledge, it does the trick. But I've got one problem, I want users to see their current standings, and that also works fine, but everytime the "command"(.xp) is used, it returns an error in my console. It do output the desired things in discord though. Any idea on how to fix this is much appreciated.

**The code**

```
//Levelup system.
var stats = {};
if (fs.existsSync('stats.json')) {
   stats = jsonfile.readFileSync('stats.json');
}

client.on('message', (message) => {

 if (message.guild.id != '335008833267040256')return;{

   if (message.author.id == client.user.id)
       return;

   if (message.guild.id in stats === false) {
       stats[message.guild.id] = {};
   }

   const guildStats = stats[message.guild.id];
   if (message.author.id in guildStats === false) {
       guildStats[message.author.id] = {
           xp: 0,
           level: 0,
           last_message: 0
       };
   }

   const userStats = guildStats[message.author.id];
   if (Date.now() - userStats.last_message > 10000) {
       userStats.xp += random.int(10, 25);
       userStats.last_message = Date.now();

       const xpToNextLevel = 5 * Math.pow(userStats.level, 2) + 50 * userStats.level + 100;
       if (userStats.xp >= xpToNextLevel) {
           userStats.level++;

           if (userStats.level >= 5) {
             message.member.addRole('495558358380838913');
           }
           if (userStats.level >= 10) {
             message.member.addRole('634538508618301445');
           }
           if (userStats.level >= 25) {
             message.member.addRole('634538456265261081');
           }
            if (userStats.level >= 50) {
             message.member.addRole('634539458594865154');
           }
            if (userStats.level >= 100) {
             message.member.addRole('634539508444168203');
           }

           userStats.xp = userStats.xp - xpToNextLevel;
           message.channel.send(message.author + ' has reached level ' + userStats.level + '. **' + xpToNextLevel + '** XP needed for next level.');
       }


       jsonfile.writeFileSync('stats.json', stats);

       console.log(message.author.username + ' now has ' + userStats.xp + 'XP. ' + xpToNextLevel + 'XP needed for next level.');
             if (message.content.startsWith (".xp")) {
                  message.reply ('you are level '+ userStats.level + ', with ' + userStats.xp + ' exp. ' + xpToNextLevel + ' exp is needed for next level.');
                   }

   }
}
   const parts = message.content.split(' ');
     });

fs.readFile('stats.json', (err, data) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   let ShowStats = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(data);
   //change to ^ stats to show better info
});
```

**Console output log**

```
(node:11) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: userStats is not defined
at Client.client.on (/home/container/index.js:272:64)
at Client.emit (events.js:203:15)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
at Receiver.emit (events.js:198:13)
(node:11) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Your error log says that the problem is at line 272: what's at that line?

Answer (score 0):

Im terrible sorry. I screwed up and forgot to remove some older code that called this as a command where this variable didnt exist.